# How can I turn off liferay filter StripFilter?

Tags: liferay

According to the documentation, exclusion of StripFilter is very easy.
It should be enough to set proper value:

```
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter=false
```

The problem is that entry for *com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter*
is missing in my portal.properties - what does it mean, when I cannot find this entry?
What is the default value for missing entries?

Comment: Please mention your liferay version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *your* `portal.properties` doesn't have the entry, it might be an ancient version (?). The current version [has this entry](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Servlet%20Filters) and you override it in `portal-ext.properties`. *That* file indeed won't have the entry until you explicitly add it.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that, as of today (Liferay 7), the StripFilter is disabled by default.

https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-95552